# Marker pin bouncing to another location on map after zoom (not on my latitude or longitude)

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

This is my code in eclipse and when I zoom on my map and tap on my pin (`Marker`) it doesn't direct to my latitude and longitude, instead it moves to different location.

```
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.flat(true);
        markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_client_org));
        markerOptions.title(getResources().getString(
                R.string.text_source_pin_title));
        markerOptions.position(
                new LatLng(latLng.latitude,
                        latLng.longitude));
        markerSource = map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

```
private void setMarker(LatLng latLng, boolean isSource) {
        if (!MapFragment.this.isVisible())
            return;
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity().getCurrentFocus() != null) {
            // inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity()
            // .getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            activity.hideKeyboard();
        }

        if (latLng != null && map != null) {
            if (isSource) {
                if (markerSource == null) {
                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.flat(true);
                    markerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);
                    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.pin_client_org));
                    markerOptions.title(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.text_source_pin_title));
                    markerOptions.position(
                            new LatLng(latLng.latitude,
                                    latLng.longitude));
                    markerSource = map.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    //markerSource.setDraggable(false);
                } else {
                    markerSource.setPosition(latLng);
                }
                CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);

            } else {
                if (markerDestination == null) {
                    MarkerOptions opt = new MarkerOptions();
                    opt.position(latLng);
                    opt.title(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.text_destination_pin_title));
                    opt.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.destination_pin));
                    markerDestination = map.addMarker(opt);

                    markerDestination.setDraggable(true);

                    if (markerSource != null) {
                        LatLngBounds.Builder bld = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

                        bld.include(new LatLng(
                                markerSource.getPosition().latitude,
                                markerSource.getPosition().longitude));
                        bld.include(new LatLng(
                                markerDestination.getPosition().latitude,
                                markerDestination.getPosition().longitude));
                        //LatLngBounds latLngBounds = bld.build();
                        //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(
                        //  latLngBounds, 30));
                    } else {
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
                    }

                } else {
                    markerDestination.setPosition(latLng);
                }
            }

            getAddressFromLocation(markerSource.getPosition(), etSource);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(
                            R.string.unable_location),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // activity.layoutDestination.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // activity.tvTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    activity.btnNotification.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    activity.tvTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    activity.setIcon(R.drawable.fare_info);
    activity.setTitle(getString(R.string.text_make_request));
    activity.btnNotification.setOnClickListener(this);
    // etSource = activity.etSource;
    // activity.imgClearDst.setOnClickListener(this);
    adapter=new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(activity, R.layout.autocomplete_list_text);

    adapterDestination=new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(activity, R.layout.autocomplete_list_text);

    etSource.setAdapter(adapter);
    locHelper=new LocationHelper(activity);

    locHelper.setLocationReceivedLister(this);
    etDestination.setAdapter(adapterDestination);
    etSource.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            etSource.setText("");
            layoutMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (sendReqLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                cancelConfirmation();
            }
        }
    });

    etSource.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange (View v,boolean hasFocus){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hasFocus) {
                etSource.setText("");
                layoutMarker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (sendReqLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    cancelConfirmation();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    etSource.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3){
            final String selectedDestPlace = adapter.getItem(arg2);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final LatLng latlng = getLocationFromAddress(selectedDestPlace);
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            isMapTouched = true;
                            curretLatLng = latlng;
                            isSource = true;
                            map.clear(); //25-02-2016
                            setMarker(curretLatLng, isSource);
                            //setMarkerOnRoad(curretLatLng, curretLatLng);
                            animateCameraToMarker(curretLatLng, true);
                            stopUpdateProvidersLoaction();
                            getAllProviders(curretLatLng);

                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

This is what my code is. Please help me to understand this vague problem.

Comment: I tried running your code (changing only the icon and the title values) and managed to receive the correct behavior when tapping the `Marker` (map camera directs to the Marker location). Did you perhaps set an `OnMarkerClickListener` on the `GoogleMap` object? Also, can you provide some sample data, like what was the `LatLng` value of the Marker you are tapping, and after tapping the Marker which location did it moved to?

Comment: thanks for initiating. @sept thing is I am giving correct latitude and longitude value to marker but the thing is when I zoom in or zoom out and try to tap on pin this pin jumps to random location and sometime it works fine. One thing which I noticed is that pin get fixed where I tap only in one situation and that is when I do not do zoom in or zoom out. Please help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide your code for the activity where you initialize the map and where you add the Markers? So I can try and replicate it. Are you testing this on a device? If yes, have you tried testing it on multiple devices?

Comment: Hey @sept buddy this is what my code is please look at it and let me know if any . . .

Comment: It would really help a lot if you provide the complete code and data. Sorry. It's hard to replicate something without any data. Can you include a `LatLng` value or something?

Comment: Also, is the map actually **zooming towards** the `Marker` on load? Or does it just stay still? And to verify, is the map moving towards a different location when you **tap** the `Marker`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with map is when ever you scroll the map it changes the location and as soon as you tap anywhere on the map your tap doesn't responds where it should be so you just have manage to stop your map being scroll.

that should solve your problem.